# Ubuntu kept old partitions after reinstallation. How can I reallocate the space?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, application-development

I am new to Ubuntu and after failing to resolve some package management problems, I'm trying to reinstall it. I'm using Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 (dual boot).

Now after the attempted reinstallation it looks like the old Ubuntu installation still exists. My previous documents are visible in another drive in the name of creating `/media/`, but I intended to format all previous data and install Ubuntu all fresh.

Partition scheme of Ubuntu:

[image: Gparted screenshot]

I want to use Ubuntu for all of my development work, including web development (web apps, databases etc), programming (C, java, Python etc), app development (Android).

1. Are my partitions good enough to handle future requirements? Did I assign the wrong amount of space or the wrong locations? I need recommendation from experienced users/developers in this regard.
2. As my past documents were saved in the `/media`, is there a way I can format all and assign space to some other directory/location which would be of more use considering my development purposes?
3. In Windows it normally installs IDEs and other software in the Program Files folder. On Ubuntu I get two folders, my Home folder and root folder (/), so where will my installed software reside? Home or root? I'm asking it because whichever one it is will need to have more space than other, won't it?

thank you!

Comment: Your drive is full. Best to start over. NTFS wants 30% free to run well and at 10% free you just about cannot do a defrag as it will take a very long time.

Comment: @oldfred Are you suggesting me to format everything and start a fresh ,I fear it won't be possible for me because I've a lot of data and don't have any spare drive right now .checking my unused space its around 72.93 GB (11.35 + 22.12+ 27.89+ 10.94 GB) .so is it not possible if I can adjust/merge this remaining space to have efficient space management ??  Further I've added few more queries ,so kindly address them too .thank you!

Comment: @Zanna thanks for suggesting the edits and relevancy in my question but it could have  been better if it didn't include down-voting :( ,you can understand how crucial these numbers are for a new user like me as it restricts my use of ask Ubuntu . nevertheless I am thankful for your suggestion as it will help to improve  my posts further and I have edited my question as par as your suggestions :)

Comment: @Zanna Thanks for being so gracious and helpful ,I'll remember your suggestion further :)

Comment: However you add it up, you do not have enough free space for efficent use of system. Your Windows is so full, it should be slow. Have you attempted a defrag lately? And if you do not have good backups to other drives, note pural, then your data is not valuable. Hard drive could fail tomorrow and then what do you do?

Comment: Dear @oldfred I already said my new install didn't removed my past ubuntu data so it still exist in sda6/ext4 directory which is around 62.35GB .Now if I add this to my current remaining space which is around 72.93GB then it will become 135.28 GB . Do you still feel this 135.28 GB is not enough ? I've just formatted my sda6 drive so that drive is almost free .I don't know why ubuntu didn't deleted my past data in my fresh install even though I have chosen that option rather it assigned same by creating a media directory sda6 .

Comment: I didn't attempted defrag but as you suggested I will check that option too  . as par as question of value of data is concerned then I would say food holds inevitable importance to human life but still there are people who don't have food but that doesn't mean their life becomes unworthy ,isn't it? . thank you for your valuable suggestions :)